# Add an element at a specific point with XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add an element at a certain point. See comments in the code.

```
<Country>
  <State>
    <Coordinate point="foo" /> <!-- That worked.-->
    <Cali>
        <Coordinate point="bar" /> <!-- How does that work in this case?-->
    </Cali>
  </State>
</Country>
```

So far my code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(test.xml);
var coordinateElement = new XElement("Coordinate");
coordinateElement.Add(new XAttribute("point", "foo"));

doc.Root.Element("State").Add(coordinateElement);
doc.Save(test.xml);
```

That worked fine to add an element `<Coordinate>` after `<State>`.

But when i want to add it after `<Cali>` ...

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(test.xml);
var coordinateElement = new XElement("Coordinate");
coordinateElement.Add(new XAttribute("point", "bar"));

doc.Element("State").Add(coordinateElement);
doc.Save(test.xml);
```

I get the following error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: `doc.Element("State")` returns null, because the root element is `Country`, not `State`. Note how in your working code you have `doc.Root.Element("State")`. (It's not clear to me why you thought removing the `.Root` part would change to adding the element within `Cali`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the great [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) pointed out, in your second statement the `doc` is missing the `Root`, to prevent the null reference.

Also Element does only look at direct children, so you first need to get to the `State` node and then to the `Cali` node. All in all it should look something like this:

```
doc.Root.Element("State").Element("Cali").Add(coordinateElement);
```